# Screensaver that leaves desktops active, but overlays an animation to prevent damage?

Tags: windows, display

I recently hit a scenario with an LCD where the screen was having some burning or damage issues for leaving the screen on and with a sustained image for too long. A traditional screensaver has resolved that issue, but this computer is used to monitor some things and so the data is always needing to be updated and visible.

*Is there a non-traditional screensaver that overlays a translucent animation over multiple displays while retaining the activity of the monitors and their presentation of data?*

Some kind of water or wave or bubbles would be ideal it seems, but I've not found any such option to date that does this. This is for Windows, but it would likewise be nice to find such an option for macOS and Linux as well.

Comment: I don't see how such a screen saver would help. If the majority of the pixels still shows the original desktop, the same pixels will have burning or damage. If a pixel is affected only 5% of the time, your display will only last 5% longer.

Comment: I'd rather try to identify other methods, e.g. activating the Eco-mode or turning off Gamer-mode. Other than gaming mode which uses voltage spikes to get faster refresh rates I can hardly believe LCDs are even affected by this.

Comment: It has helped. I've seen it demonstrably save the life of several monitors over the years and most recently it is saving one of my monitors that I paid a couple hundred dollars for about 5 years ago. There was a line across the entire display and upon turning on the screensaver (it does not have any such eco mode), the monitor is looking great again after two weeks.

Comment: Okay, I will believe you. Thanks for the information.